# How to Show Code Runner Shortcut In VS Code

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-code-runner, coderunner

How can I show the Code Runner shortcut in Visual Studio Code if I mistakenly hid it?"

[image: 1]

I was using Visual Studio Code and I accidentally hid the Code Runner shortcut. Is there a way to show it again? I have tried searching in the keyboard shortcuts settings but can't seem to find it. Any help would be appreciated (P.S I Know Many Of You will Say Use a Shortcut Key, or Reinstall the CodeRunner & VS Code But All Is Not Working)

How Can I get Code runner Shortcut Again

Answer (score 0):

1. Make sure that you enabled your "Code Runner" extension
2. Go to the top right corner of VS Code to find a button that looks like three dots (...)
3. Right click on it and press "Run Code"

   [image: run code]
4. The Run Code button should reappear now

Comment: I Know Its There But AnsonH I Want to Add That Shortcut Again (I am Focusing On That Icon)

Comment: Do you mean whether there's a shortcut to hide and show the "Run Code" button icon?

Answer (score 0):

[@AnsonH](/users/11067496)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75305578/11107541) is most likely the solution you need:

> 1. Make sure that you enabled your "Code Runner" extension
> 2. Go to the top right corner of VS Code to find a button that looks like three dots (...)
> 3. Right click on it and press "Run Code"
>
>    [image: run code]
> 4. The Run Code button should reappear now

But there's a chance you accidentally messed with the `code-runner.showRunIconInEditorTitleMenu` (accidentally set it to `false`), in which case you just need to remove the line that sets it to `false` from your [settings.json files](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/settings#_settingsjson), or set it to `true` explicitly.